# difficulty displaying data in my listview android

Tags: android, listview

I have problem with displaying data in my listview. it's not displaying vertically.

here's my code:

```
private ListView lv;
private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.meal_result);
    BreakFastLog info = new BreakFastLog(this);
    info.open();

    String data1 = info.getMealNameData();
    //String data2 = info.getServingData();

    results.add(data1);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lvBF);   
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 

    info.close();
}
```

and my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvBF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

What's wrong with this? please help me figure out what makes it displayed horizontally.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: *it's not displaying vertically.* - and how does it display now?

Comment: please help me figure out what makes it displayed horizontally.

Comment: I don't see how your `ListView` could be display horizontally. You currently have one item in the `ListView` so you'll see one row. I don't see how this could possible go wrong. Maybe you could convince me with an image.

Comment: data1 has list of user input.

Comment: @Luksprog i added the image

Comment: I guess you put all the items from the results in one `String`, justbreak the string like this: `String data1 = info.getMealNameData();
    //String data2 = info.getServingData();
    String[] dataBreak = data1.split(" ");    
    lv = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lvBF);   
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataBreak));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gone through your code,

You have a only one String  value `String data1 = info.getMealNameData();` 
in your `ArrayList<String> results`. And results is added to your List Adapter.

So only one row displayed in your `ListView`.

So You have to either make a `String[]` for all user Inputs instead of your one `String data1` and pass that `String[]` to your List Adapter.

**Update:**

```
String data1 = info.getMealNameData();
String[] inputData = data1.split(" ");
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, inputData ));
```

Comment: Hi i added the screenshot of my app

Comment: Just split your data1 string with space " " and make a `String[]` and pass this `String[]` to your Adapter.

Comment: @user1705590 - If you write a comment related to question post your comment below question.

Comment: @user1705590 how about if i added the 2nd data, data2? I know i have to create another question for this, but if you could help me display this in 2 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Try `<RelativeLayout>` in your xml instead of `<LinearLayout>`. And add this to your listview

```
 <ListView
         android:id="@id+/yourListViewid"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
     </ListView>
```